# Speed up Heroku deploy for Rails 4 app

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a way to cache precompiled assets for a Rails 4 app on Heroku?

I followed the instructions from [this blog post](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/faster-deploys) and some of the heroku docs, which sped things up considerdably, but still taking just as long  to precompile assets.

Here's the relevant section from my gemfile (also found it necessary to [enable the 'user-env-compile' lab](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile)):

```
group :production, :staging do
  # for heroku, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-integration-gems
  gem 'rails_12factor'

  # https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31
  gem 'rack-cache'
  gem 'kgio'

  # faster heroku deploys (http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/faster-deploys)
  gem 'memcachier'
  gem 'dalli'
end
```

And from my config/production.rb and config/staging.rb:

```
  # Neither of the below worked (tried separately)
  # config.assets.cache_store = :dalli_store
  config.assets.configure {|env| env.cache = ActiveSupport::Cache.lookup_store(:dalli_store) }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to make the asset compilation take less time, or trying to compile assets elsewhere so they don't have to be compiled by your app? "Speeding things up considerably" and "a way to cache precompiled assets" sound like different tasks to me.

Comment: [This Dev Center article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) has information on caching static assets, and is expanded on in [this blog post](http://www.neilmiddleton.com/heroku-asset-pipeline-faq/)

Comment: Trying to avoid re-compiling assets that haven't changed, since that's what seems to make the deploys take so long. Is precompiling locally the only way?

Comment: The Dev Center article mentions three options: compiling locally, compiling during slug compilation, and compiling at runtime. I'm guessing you do *not* want runtime, as it could slow down your app?

Comment: The blog article mentions "If you push your own compiled assets into source control Heroku will recognise this and not try another precompile". He seems to indicate we should *not* do this, as it's one more difference where things could go wrong. But if you have a large number of assets that haven't changed, perhaps checking them into source control would work for you?

Comment: Do you have anything in your `config.assets.precompile` setting that should *not* be precompiled? That may be taking extra time.

Comment: Hey @Jay. Sorry I can't contribute to this in a more direct way, but I want you to know that I've also been searching for an answer to this, and I've read the same articles and tried the same thing you have (as you posted in your code snippets). I've been getting the TwilightZone effect here where it seems people keep glossing over what I would otherwise consider a glaring-lowhanging-fruit (deploy speedup via asset caching) so take heart; you're not alone in this quest! I will stay tuned and update here if I find anything on my end :)

Comment: Thanks @Volte, not a big pain point for me at the moment but I'll update here as well if I find a good solution!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the assets_sync gem.

Comment: Interesting-- I'll give it a shot. Don't see any specific mention of Rails 4, hopefully no breaking changes